# What is the development effort for implementing "login with facebook" on large eCommerce site in JSP?

Tags: jsp, authentication, facebook

I am trying to scope out the development effort associated with implementing the "login with Facebook" option on our website. 
We operate a fairly large eCommerce travel website running on a JSP environment. We have already a user account feature, based on a MySQL database. The only requirement for a user to create an account currently is to provide an email address as their loginId and a password.

In order to make it even easier for users to register and sign-in to our site, we would like to offer a "login with facebook" button (just like Kayak.com does), so that a user can register to our site based on their Facebook account. By authorizing our application, we would pull their email information and create an account on our website.

My assumption is that this would be a relatively simple maintenance project, costing 10 Man Days of development & QA max. I would like to get some feedback from other webmasters that have implemented a similar feature to see if my rough estimate is in line with reality. 
Thanks in advance for the insights you can share with me.

Lothaire

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 10 days will be enough, but I'm not sure how many developers you will have working on this. If you have not already I would do some more research on this, it might give you a better idea of the amount of work involved. 
Some quick Google searches gave me this.

[Authentication-Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

[Facebook for Websites-Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login)

Comment: The thing is that I practice web development as a hobby and I have implemented Flickr's OAUTH authentication API on my personal site in a few hours. As a proof of concept, I also put up a test page that implements the Facebook Login API to get the user's email. It took me less than one hour.

I realize when talking about a big eCommerce website, the scale is different, but I would like to have a better understanding of the effort required and the technical implications that would justify a Man Day cost greater than a dozen.